# How can i open just one modal through a map function

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap4-modal

im trying to make a subpage for a record label, i need to display all the artists on cards and then have their full profile displayed on a modal, whenever i try to open the modal all of them open and close when i click the card button, i've tried creating a constructor(props) with state component but wasnt able to make the state recieve the key id of the artist  . i've been trying for weeks trying to adapt other examples to my own code with no results, Thank you so much for your time!

```
import React, {useState, setShow, Component} from 'react';
import {CardDeck, Navbar, NavLink, Col, Row, Image, Container, Card, CardImg, CardBody, CardText } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'; 
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

const Artistas = [ {id:1,
img:require("../assets/images/artists-01.jpg"), 
title: 'Artist 1', 
content: 'Lorem Ipsum',
    musica:"https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/1wA3nwZy9EriceVVQlEmEx",
    genres:["Punk ", "Rock"]},
  
    {id: 2, 
img:require("../assets/images/artists-04.jpg"), 
title: "Artist 2", 
content: 'lorem ipsum',
    musica:"https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/1wA3nwZy9EriceVVQlEmEx"},
   ];


function ArtistsPage() {
  
    
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

const Artistxs = Artistas.map(artist => 
<div>
<Card key={artist.id}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src={artist.img} />
  <Card.Body>
  <Button onClick={handleShow}>{artist.title}</Button>
 <Card.Text>
  </Card.Text> 
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
<>
<Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={false}
        centered
        size="lg"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>{artist.title}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body className="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <Image src={artist.img} />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>{artist.content}</p>
  </div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} >
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
</>
</div>
 )


  return(
    <div>
      <Container className="container">
<Row className="row">
  <Col className="">{Artistxs}
</Col>
</Row>
</Container>
</div>
  );

}



export default ArtistsPage;
```

Comment: Why r u creating  instances of Model with map?

Comment: Creating separate component for a Model and passing id or a index as a props to it on button click to it should work.
According to id or index then u can show the data in a model.

Comment: hi @GurulingKumbhar because i haven't been able to make it render outside the map function....  do you have an example? i just moved the Modal below the map inside the ArtistPage, but still cant make it to work, thank you so much for your time

Comment: ok, let me create one basic example for u in answers. May help u to resolve.

Comment: @GurulingKumbhar thank u so much for your help ! :) the StackOverflow community is amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate component for Modal and pass the object through Props to display relevant info and handle modal events.

In example below, not toggling the actual modal but u can use the props to toggle it.

```
function ArtistAddtionalInfo(props) {
  return (
  // Modal can be here with details in artistInfo and other props 
  <div className="modal_dummy"> 
    Below Props can be used to handle actual model popup 
    <h1> Hello, { props.artistInfo.title }</h1>
    <div>{ props.artistInfo.id }</div>
    <div>{ props.artistInfo.img }</div>
    <div>{ props.artistInfo.content }</div>
    <div>showModel: {props.showModel ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
    <button onClick = {() => props.handleModalClose()} > close </button>
  </div>
  
  )
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        items: [ {id:1,
img:"../assets/images/artists-01.jpg", 
title: 'Artist 1', 
content: 'Lorem Ipsum',
    musica:"https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/1wA3nwZy9EriceVVQlEmEx",
    genres:["Punk ", "Rock"]},
  
    {id: 2, 
img:"../assets/images/artists-04.jpg", 
title: "Artist 2", 
content: 'lorem ipsum',
    musica:"https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/1wA3nwZy9EriceVVQlEmEx"},
   ],
   artistInfo:  {},
   isShowModel: false
    }
  }
  
handleShow = (artist) =>{
     this.setState({
         artistInfo:artist,
       isShowModel: true
     });
  }
  
handleOnhide = () =>{
     this.setState({
         isShowModel: false
     });
}

render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="">
                { 
                this.state.items.map(artist => 
                   <div className="card" key={artist.id}>
                    <img className="card_image" src={artist.img} />
                    <div className="card_body">
                        <button onClick={ () => { this.handleShow(artist)}}> {artist.title} </button>
                        <div className="card_text">
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
             )
            } 
          </div>
        </div>
        {
        this.state.isShowModel &&
        <ArtistAddtionalInfo 
          artistInfo = { this.state.artistInfo }
          showModel = {this.state.isShowModel}
          handleModalClose = {() => {this.handleOnhide()}}
        />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

**JSFiddle**
[see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/01a9qdft/157/)

Answer (score 0):

You only need 1 `Modal`.  So you can move `Modal` out of your map.

Then, you need to figure out how to indicate which artist to show in the `Modal`.

One way to do that is to pass the `artist.id`:

```
<Button onClick={handleShow(artist.id)}>{artist.title}</Button>
```

But now `handleShow` needs to return a function:

```
const handleShow = (artistId) => () => setShow(artistId);
```

I've also changes `show` to be which artist id instead of a boolean.  (This assumes artist ids will not be zero, at the moment)

Once in the `Modal`, you need to find the selected artist:

```
Artistxs.find(artist => artist.id === artistId);
```

This should get you going.

Comment: thank u so much for your quick response, i moved the Modal down the map, i added the onClick to the button i did a ```function Modalx(){ Artistxs.find(artist => artist.id === artistId); return (<Modal artistId={artistId}
          onHide={handleClose}
          size="lg"></Modal>) render (<Modalx/>) //also changed  const [artistId, setShow] = useState(artistId);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = (artistId) => () => setShow(artistId); // and called the function in a return(  <Col >{Artistxs}{Modalx}
</Col>)``` but still i cant make it work, thank u so much <3